# Multi-module Spring Boot app with more than one database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, multi-module

My home pet-project is a multimodule maven spring boot application

```
sbsuite-pom
    |_ web (Spring Boot application)
        |_ pom.xml
    |_ frontendUI (VueJs app)
        |_ pom.xml
    |_ sbsuitedata (MySql persistence layer)
        |_ pom.xml
    |_ pom.xml
```

I manage to insert jpa project from online course as a submodule "sbsuitedata",
but here is a problem, - properties files from "sbsuitedata" not visible in SpringBoot web module until I move them into sbsuite-pom\web project.
What if I want to have more than one persistent layer submodule, let's say one for MySql and other for Oracle?
So each persistent layer submodule will work with it's own database and have it's own property file to list connections.

What is the right approach to handle such requirement?